# How do time-limited keys work for e.g. DCP files?

Tags: encryption

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_cinema under `How Digital Cinema Works` it states that the decryption keys are time-limited and expire after the end of the booked time. From a high level perspective, how does this work? Is timestamp information retrieved from a trusted source over the wire or does the proprietary software used to decrypt the file adhere to the timestamp coded in the key?